# Defeating enemy crab by cutting off legs and claws

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The following is from the MIT-Harvard Tournament:

> You are trapped in ancient Japan, and a giant enemy crab is approaching! You must defeat it by
>   cutting off its two claws and six legs and attacking its weak point for massive damage. You cannot
>   cut off any of its claws until you cut off at least three of its legs, and you cannot attack its weak point
>   until you have cut off all of its claws and legs. In how many ways can you defeat the giant enemy crab?
>   (Note that the legs are distinguishable, as are the claws.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is $6\times 5\times 4 = 120$ ways to cut the first three legs.

Then there is $5!$ ways to cut the remaining $5$ members. Indeed, you have first to choose one of the 5 remaining members to cut, then one of the four remaining, etc. This gives you

$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 5! = 120$ ways to cut the 5 remainings members (3 legs, two claws)

Finally, there is only one way to defeat the crab : its only weak point!

That give us $120 \times 120 = 14400$ ways to defeat the crab.

I just hope the giant crab is edible...

Comment: could you please tell me how do we have 5! ways after cutting 3 legs ?

Comment: @batman1 : added a little explaination.